# How to set the VScode terminal so it recognizes the python shebang of the scripts and run them with the proper python version?

Tags: terminal, python, visual-studio-code

By default, we must choose the python version here:
[image]

I know the python shebangs (e.g. `#!python3.9`) are made for the launcher.

But is there a way for the terminal to automatically launch the script with the right python version using the shebang at the beginning of the script?